# JSONP and GET with callbacks - help needed correcting errors

Tags: php, jquery, json, callback

This is my JSONP file:

```
<?php
   header('Content-type: application/javascript;');
header("access-control-allow-origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
  //db connection detils
  $host = "localhost";
  $user = "test";
  $password = "test";
  $database = "myradiostation1";

  //make connection
  $server = mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);
  $connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

  //query the database
  $query = mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(start, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS start, 
                                   DATE_FORMAT(end, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') AS end FROM radiostation1");

    //loop through and return results
  for ($x = 0, $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query); $x < $numrows; $x++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    $shows[$x] = array("id" => $row["id"], "startminutes" => $row["startminutes"], "start" => $row["start"], "endminutes" => $row["endminutes"],"end" => $row["end"],"mediumname" => $row["mediumname"], "longname" => $row["longname"], "description" => $row["description"],"short_id" => $row["short_id"],"promomessage" => $row["promomessage"],"email" => $row["email"],"phonenumber" => $row["phonenumber"],"textnumber" => $row["textnumber"],"textprefix" => $row["textprefix"],"showimage" => $row["showimage"],"longdescription" => $row["longdescription"],"facebooklink" => $row["facebooklink"],"otherlink" => $row["otherlink"],"websitelink" => $row["websitelink"],"keywords" => $row["keywords"] );     
  }

  //echo JSON to page
  $response = $_GET["callback"] . "(" . json_encode($shows) . ");";
  echo $response; 

?>
```

It *does* work, up to a point, but getting the {"success":true,"error":"","data":{"schedule": as seen at [this site](http://radioplayer.bauerradio.com/schedule.php?callback=&name=Rock%20FM) before my json_encode is where I am.

However, I cannot get it to display any data in my table, although it DOES produce code on-screen when I view it at http://www.myradio1.localhost/onairschedule.php.

The actual code is stored at http://www.myradiostations.localhost/schedule.php

and the callback function works OK, one example being http://www.myradiostations.localhost/schedule.php?callback=?&name=Northern+FM and http://www.myradiostations.localhost/schedule.php?callback=?&name=Southern+FM but what do I need to do to make it change like in these examples:
[this example](http://radioplayer.bauerradio.com/schedule.php?callback=?&name=Hallam%20FM) and [this example](http://radioplayer.bauerradio.com/schedule.php?callback=?&name=Wave%20105), and to generate an error message like [this](http://radioplayer.bauerradio.com/schedule.php?callback=?&name=) if no such file exists.

I'm halfway there, just need some advice on fixing my code!

Basically, what I'm trying to do... get a JSONP to work in my HTML table which will vary the content depending on the URL in my javascript file on my page, which is:

```
var doFades = true;

var LocalhostRadioStations = {
  Schedule : {}
};

$(document).ready(function(){

  LocalhostRadioStations.Schedule.days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']

  LocalhostRadioStations.Schedule.Show = function () {
    _s = null;
    _startDate = null;
    _endDate = null;
    this.days = LocalhostRadioStations.Schedule.days;
    _selector = '';

    this.setShow = function(s) {
      this._s = s;

      this._startDate = new Date( parseInt(s.startminutes, 10) * 1000);
      this._endDate = new Date(parseInt(s.endminutes, 10) * 1000 ); 

    };

    this.getEndDate = function(){
      return this._endDate;
    }

    this.getStartDate = function(){ 
      return this._startDate;
    }

    this._getShowDay = function (){
      return this.days[this.getStartDate().getDay()];
    };

    this._getShowUnitsTaken = function(){
      // if it's the same day
      return this._getEndUnits() - this._getStartUnits();
    };

    this._getEndUnits = function(){   
      if(this.getEndDate().getHours() == 0)
      {
        //console.log(this._s.longname  +' ends at midnight');
        return 48;
      }

      return this.getEndDate().getMinutes() !== 0 ? (this.getEndDate().getHours() * 2) : (this.getEndDate().getHours() * 2);
    };

    this._getStartUnits = function(){
      if(this.getStartDate().getHours() == 0)
      {
        return 0;
      }

      return this.getStartDate().getMinutes() !== 0 ? (this.getStartDate().getHours() * 2) : (this.getStartDate().getHours() * 2);
    };

    this.getCellPositions = function() {
      return {
        'start' : this.getStartDate(),
        'end' : this.getEndDate(),
        'colIndex' : this.getStartDate().getDay() + 2,
        'startUnits' : this._getStartUnits(),
        'endUnits' : this._getEndUnits(),
        'unitsTaken' : this._getShowUnitsTaken()
      }
    };

    this.pad = function(number){
      return number < 10 ? '0'+number : number; 
    };

    // return the table cell html.
    this.toHtml = function () {

      var d = new Date();
      var units = this._getStartUnits();

      var rowspan = this._getShowUnitsTaken();    
      var desc = this._s.description;
      var name = this._s.longname;

      var starttime   = this.pad(this.getStartDate().getHours()) + ':' + this.pad(this.getStartDate().getMinutes());
      var endtime   = this.pad(this.getEndDate().getHours()) + ':' + this.pad(this.getEndDate().getMinutes());

      var site = this._s.websitelink;

      var cls = this.isActive() ? 'current-program' : '';

      var isToday = this.getStartDate().getDay() === d.getDay() ? 'active-program' : '';

      var html = '<td class="schedule-show ' + isToday + ' ' + cls + '" rowspan="' + rowspan + '" data-start="' + this.getStartDate() + '" data-end="' + this.getEndDate() + '">';
        html += '<div>';
        html += '<a href="' + site + '" title="' + desc + '">' + name + '</a>';
        html += '</div>';
        if(doFades)
        {
          html += '<div class="schedule_details clearfix" style="display:none;">';
          html += '<img width="105px" height="105px" alt="' + desc + '" src="' + this._s.showimage + '">';
          html += '<strong>' + name + '</strong>';
          html += '<p>' + desc + '</p>';
          html += '<span>' + starttime + ' - ' + endtime +'</span>';
          html += '</div>';
        }
        html += '</td>';      

      return html;
    };

    this.setTableSelector = function(sel){
      this._selector = sel;
    };

    // check if we should add the active class.
    this.isActive = function(){
      var t = new Date();

      return  t >= this.getStartDate() && t <= this.getEndDate();
    };
  };

  LocalhostRadioStations.Schedule.ScheduleGen = function(){

    return {
      insertShow : function(show) {
        var p = show.getCellPositions();

        $('tr#units-' + p.startUnits).append(show.toHtml());
      },

      init : function (stationName){
        var self = this;

        // load the schedule.
        $.getJSON('http://www.myradiostations.localhost/schedule.php?callback=?&name=', {
          name: 'Northern FM'
        }, function(json){
          // loop each show and append to our giant table.
          // this is well sick.

          if(json.success === false)
          {
            $('.content-inner table').remove();

            $('<div>errors</div>').appendTo('.content-inner');
          }
          else
          {
            var currentDay = '';
            var day = 0;
            // highlight the current time..
            var d = new Date();
            var weekStart = new Date();

            weekStart.setDate(d.getDate()-6-(d.getDay()||7));

            $.each(json.data.schedule, function(i, broadcast){


              var dStart = new Date( parseInt(broadcast.startminutes, 10) * 1000);
              var dEnd = new Date(parseInt(broadcast.endminutes, 10) * 1000 ); 


              /*// transform to a show object defined above, if the show spans 2 days we create two show objects.
              // IF THE SHOW STARTS/ENDS AT MIDNIGHT, DON'T SPLIT IT.
              if(dStart.getHours() !== 0 && dEnd.getHours() !== 0 && dStart.getDate() != dEnd.getDate())
              {
                var showOne = new LocalhostRadioStations.Schedule.Show();
                showOne.setShow(broadcast);

                // set to midnight 
                showOne.getEndDate().setHours(0);
                showOne.getEndDate().setMinutes(dStart.getMinutes());


                // append first half of show.
                self.insertShow(showOne);

                // handle second half.
                var showTwo = new LocalhostRadioStations.Schedule.Show();
                showTwo.setShow(broadcast);

                showTwo.getStartDate().setDate(showTwo.getStartDate().getDate() + 1);
                showTwo.getStartDate().setHours(0);
                showTwo.getStartDate().setMinutes(dEnd.getMinutes());

                //console.log('2nd Half Start: ' + showTwo.getStartDate());
                //console.log('2nd Half End: ' + showTwo.getEndDate());

                self.insertShow(showTwo);


              }
              else
              {*/
                var show = new LocalhostRadioStations.Schedule.Show();

                show.setShow(broadcast);
                show.setTableSelector('table#schedule');

                // add the show to the table. Thankfully the order these come out the API means they get added 
                // in the right place. So don't change the schedule builder code!

                self.insertShow(show);
              //}


            });

            var days = LocalhostRadioStations.Schedule.days;   

            // apply the current day / time classes 
            $('th:contains('+ days[d.getDay()]+')').addClass('active');

            $('td.time').each(function(i, cell){
              // get the value, convert to int. 
              var hours = $(cell).html().split(':')[0];

              // compare the hours with now, add class if matched. 
              if(parseInt(hours, 10) === d.getHours())
              {
                $(cell).addClass('current_time');
              }
            });
          }


          if(doFades)
          {
            // apply events to show info fade in / out.
            $('td.schedule-show').hover(function(){
              $(this).find('.schedule_details').fadeIn('fast');
            }, function(){
              $(this).find('.schedule_details').fadeOut('fast');
            });
          }
        });


      }
    };
  }();


  LocalhostRadioStations.Schedule.ScheduleGen.init(twittiName);

});
```

It should change the schedule according to the JSONP, but what do I do to fix it?

Basically, I am trying to make my own localhost version of http://radioplayer.bauerradio.com/schedule.php?callback=&name=Rock+FM and its JSON / JSONP (I am not sure exactly what type the original is, but then again the site is experimental and on a .localhost domain) for testing purposes where the content is taken from the database, and changes according to station name, e.g. http://radioplayer.bauerradio.com/schedule.php?callback=&name=Metro+Radio and http://radioplayer.bauerradio.com/schedule.php?callback=&name=Forth+One etc.

Edit: The full code for my page can be seen at http://pastebin.com/ENhR6Q9j

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what's missing, but from the code you gave so far, I made a jsfiddle:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mfirdaus/8G2kJ/)

I modified some things to make it work (mostly appending stuff), because I don't know your original HTML file. But I also made some changes based on what you say you wanted. First of all I modified your `$.getJSON` call to be something like:

```
$.getJSON('http://radioplayer.bauerradio.com/schedule.php?callback=?', {
          name: stationName //stationName is from the argument passed
        }, function(json){...})
```

Which should give back the station based on what is passed to

```
LocalhostRadioStations.Schedule.ScheduleGen.init(twittiName);
```

To make it more interesting, I also added a bit of code that reads from the url. In this case if you go to the page with a `domain.htm/page?Northern FM` it will read the text after the `?` and put it in `twittiName`.

```
var twittiName="Rock FM"; //default station

if(window.location.search){
   twittiName=window.location.search.substring(1)   //or window.location.hash
}
```

Tried to look for other stations that might be on your publics site, but so far I could only test with "?Rock+FM". But does mean you can show the errors, which your code can handle as it is.

- [`?Rock+FM`](http://jsfiddle.net/mfirdaus/8G2kJ/show/?Rock%20FM)
- [`?Random Name`](http://jsfiddle.net/mfirdaus/8G2kJ/show/?Random%20Name)

So it seems that your code mostly works but do comment if I have missed anything.

Comment: Thank you for that answer! It looks really useful. What I am trying to do is use code from my own database rather than use the JSON linked to online - the bauerradio domain (which is a public site). As for my code, here's the full link: http://pastebin.com/ENhR6Q9j .I am trying to make my own version of it basically, for localhost testing.